# Trying to do a spotlight effect in android canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

I have a canvas and a simple bitmap for background image, fills the whole screen. I created a rect painted black and set it's alpha to 250 in order to make a "dark" effect on the background image. My aim to make a simple circle object that reveals the place it's hovering above. I tried thinking in many ways how to excecute it and failed.

I think the best way is to create a simple circle that manages to decrease the darkness alpha on the position it hovers above, but I have no idea how to do it.

The relevant part of my code:

```
private ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(Color.BLACK, 1);
private Paint darkPaint = new Paint(Color.BLACK), paint = new Paint(), paint2 = new Paint();//The style of the text and dark.

public DarkRoomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        myChild = this;
        darkPaint.setColorFilter(filter);
                darkPaint.setAlpha(250);
        paint2.setAlpha(10);
        paint.setAlpha(50);
    }

private void loadGFX() {//Loads all of this view GFX file.
        backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),                R.drawable.darkroomscreen);

        lightImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.light);

    }

private void drawGFX(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImage, 0, 0, paint2);//The backgeound image.
      canvas.drawRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, darkPaint);//The darkness.
      canvas.drawBitmap(lightImage, 50, 50, paint);//A spotlight.
}
```

Any ideas how I should get it done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the spotlight, you could draw a circle of the original image *over* the darkness. You'd simply need to find the correct rectangle of the original image (based on where your finger is), and then draw a circle of that particular rectangle over the darkness. Trying to look "through" the darkness won't really get you anywhere; you need to place something over it.

Comment: Yeah, but it means I need to draw the part of the background image where the spotlight is. How do I draw only part of a bitmap?

Comment: Use drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint). src is the rectangle you're cropping from the original image, and dst is the rectangle you're drawing it into the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you draw the "spotlight", you've already darkened the image with the rectangle. It would be difficult to recover information lost during that draw.

A more flexible approach would be to draw a dark rectangle with a spotlight in a separate image (that is, compose the "darkness" and spotlight alpha and color mask image first), and then draw that mask image on top of the background as a separate step. This would also let you easily do things like e.g. give the spotlight fuzzy borders.